# Simplification of a sentence - the underlying usage implied by the author

Tags: meaning, sentence, syntactic-analysis, ambiguity, complex-sentences

I encountered this sentence in 'A Caribbean Mystery' by Agatha Christie.

> Thus Raymond - and his aunt Jane - had looked properly abashed - and said 
>    'Yes,' she was afraid she was rather old-fashioned.

Its clear that it was only aunt Jane who had looked abashed from some words said by Raymond, in the upcoming lines. So, how does this line represent the same? 
The confusion is regarding the use of 'and' to imply both Raymond and his aunt.

Some clarity in this regard would help.

Comment: Is there really a dash after 'Jane'? The sentence as you quote it doesn't make sense, but in the light of your explanation it could do if you remove that dash. "Thus Raymond" means "That is what Raymond had said."

Comment: In a text I found that dash is not there, but even without it the sentence doesn't make sense. Perhaps there is a proof-reading error — they happen.

Comment: Yes, there is one, actually. I quoted it exactly, and I repeat, exactly, as it was, haha. Hence, the doubt.

Comment: That's possible. But, well, if the dash is not there, doesn't it mean that the two of them had combinedly looked abashed?

Comment: I would need to read the whole paragraph but I don't have the book.

Comment: @LumosMaxima Do you have a printed copy?

Comment: Yes, I do have a printed copy.

Comment: The portion is supposedly available here: https://www.coursehero.com/file/p4ruq54/Miss-Marple-wondered-too-And-really-To-have-sex-experience-urged-on-you-exactly/

Comment: And as for the whole book, it can be downloaded from here:
https://www.educatora.in/uploads/2/0/5/1/20513864/a_caribbean_mystery_by_agatha_christie.pdf

Comment: @LumosMaxima my browser won't let me, it says that site is insecure. But from the previous snippet, that sentence makes no sense to me at all. If it was Jane who said "Yes", why does the sentence start with "Thus Raymond".

Comment: Right. I just wanted to confirm whether there's some usage that I'm unaware of, after all. And then again, the fact that Agatha Christie is a legendary writer, kind of added to my doubt. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: She was certainly a prolific writer. Please have a look it [this](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/non_fictionreviews/3668468/The-crimes-of-Agatha-Christie.html).

Comment: Need to see the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agatha Christie’s works have been typeset many times.  It could be a printer’s error.

However, I’m inclined to think that the passage is being related by a third party, possibly in a letter, or in a description of a diary entry, or in some other form where the style can be both casual and indirect. It is possible that this “frame of reference” has been established some distance “upstream” of the sentence in question.

For example, it is possible in English to refer to oneself in the third person, in order to create a slightly distanced and ironic tone.

“Jimmy was playing in the sandbox, Ellie was on the swings, and their father here was spraying water on Uncle Bob and his son” (points to self).

Thus, Ellie - and her father here - forgetting the sandbox - Jimmy - he said that we really “had to see his castle - and Stop Hogging All the Water”. So we did.

In effect, the narrator is “getting lost” in the complexity if their narrative, but getting back on track with a clear sentence at the end.

I don’t know if that was Ms. Christie’s intent here, but it would not be unlike her to write this way.